# Threadsafe way of exposing keySet()

Tags: java, hashset

This must be a fairly common occurrence where I have a map and wish to thread-safely expose its key set:

```
public MyClass {
  Map<String,String> map = // ...
  public final Set<String> keys() {
     // returns key set
  }
}
```

Now, if my "map" is not thread-safe, this is not safe:

```
  public final Set<String> keys() {
     return map.keySet();
  }
```

And neither is:

```
  public final Set<String> keys() {
     return Collections.unmodifiableSet(map.keySet());
  }
```

So I need to create a copy, such as:

```
  public final Set<String> keys() {
     return new HashSet(map.keySet());
  }
```

However, this doesn't seem safe either because that constructor traverses the elements of the parameter and add()s them.  So while this copying is going on, a ConcurrentModificationException can happen.

So then:

```
  public final Set<String> keys() {
     synchronized(map) {
       return new HashSet(map.keySet());
     }
  }
```

seems like the solution.  Does this look right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That solution isn't particularly helpful unless you plan to also synchronize on the map everywhere it is used.  Synchronizing on it doesn't stop someone else from invoking methods on it at the same time.  It only stops them from also being able to synchronize on it.

The best solution really seems to be just use `ConcurrentHashMap` in the first place if you know you need concurrent puts and removes while someone may be iterating.  If the concurrency behavior that class offers isn't what you need, you'll probably just need to use a fully synchronized Map.

Comment: Note that I am not exposing the map itself, but only its key set.  And a copy of the key set at that.

Comment: Yes, I don't think that changes anything?  Synchronizing that block still does not fix the hazard that you were attempting to fix with it.

Comment: If you are worried about a `ConcurrentModificationException`, that means the map is being exposed in a non thread safe way...

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are correct.  It looks like the bottom line is that the underlying map needs to be threadsafe.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I would use Google Guava library. More specifically `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(Collection<? extends E>)` method. In documentation it has been said that this method is thread safe.

Comment: The docs say, "This method is safe to use even when elements is a synchronized or concurrent collection that is currently being modified by another thread"; I have not guaranteed that my "map" is synchronized.

Comment: @Jake, if your map is not synchronized then this is an unsolvable problem.

Comment: @Jake. I wonder if you are going to modify your map at runtime. If no then you could use ImmutableMap. Otherwise using ConcurrentHashMap (solution posted by Affe) is really the best choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use ConcurrentHashMap. Its keySet() is thread safe so there might be no need to synchronize or take a copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested on thread-safe iterator with exact snapshot of elements through out the iteration process then go for the below.

```
public class ThreadSafeIteratorConcurrentMap
{
    private ConcurrentMap<String, String> itrSafeMap = null;

    public ThreadSafeIteratorConcurrentCollection() {
            itrSafeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>
    }

    public void synchronized put(psConference conference, String p_key)
    {
         itrSafeMap.putIfAbsent(p_key, conference);
    }

    public psConference getConference(String p_key)
    {
        return (itrSafeMap.get(p_key));
    }

    public void synchronized remove(String p_key)
    {
        itrSafeMap.remove(p_key);
    }

    public boolean containsKey(String p_key)
    {
        return itrSafeMap.containsKey(p_key);
    }

    // Get the size of the itrSafeMap.
    public int size()
    {
        return itrSafeMap.size();
    }

    public Iterator<String> valueIterator()
    {
        return (itrSafeMap.values().iterator());
    }   

    public Iterator<String> keyIterator()
    {
        return (itrSafeMap.keySet().iterator());
    }

}
```

Then where ever you want thread safe iterator with exact snapshot of elements; then use it in synchronized block like below.

```
   synchronized(threadSafeIteratorConcurrentMapObject) {

       Iterator<String> keyItr = threadSafeIteratorConcurrentMapObject.keyIterator();
       while(keyItr.hasNext()){
        // Do whatever
       }
   }
```

If you don't mind modification on the collection while iteration; only concentrating on snapshot of elements at the time of iterator creation; then without synchronization block you can use keyItr.  Which is already thread safe; it wont through ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an temporary Map using `Collections.UnmodifiableMap`, then iterate the keyset .

Comment: This doesn't protect from ConcurrentModificationException if underlying map is not thread-safe.

Comment: When you have unmodifiable collection, you cannot do remove or add operations on the underlying map. Then how do u say it is not threadsafe.

Comment: @SureshSankar The real collection which you used at UnmodifiableMap may be changed by some other thread rit ..?

Comment: @Sugumar: unmodifiablemap prevents addition and deletion of objects,but the objects within the map can be modified. to prevent these objects being modified then do deep clone and pass it on ,instead of original object.